# web scraping and downloand images from image.google.com using selenum

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selenium

how can I web **scrape** from image.google.com using selenium?
I tried this

```
car_name_list=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="VFACy kGQAp sMi44c lNHeqe WGvvNb"]')   
car_name = []   
for i in car_name_list:   
    a = i.get_attribute('innerText') 
    print(a)   
    car_name.append(a)   
print(car_name)
```

but not getting the image file
I am not sure how to download image file

Comment: Share the URL in the question.

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: no xpath is correct but i am not getting image file

Comment: @pmadhu the url is https://images.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

After doing a search in Google Images in the form of `car_names`, the code I wrote below takes both the image and the name of the image for you. I want you to import the `base64` library in addition to yours. The summary of your problem was that you only took the link part as xpath, so the image you wanted was not where you took it, you had an error on the xpath side.

```py
import base64

img = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="VFACy kGQAp sMi44c lNHeqe WGvvNb"]/../a/div/img')

# For get name of the image
name = img.get_attribute('alt')

# For Download Image
src = img.get_attribute('src')
src = src.split(",")

imgdata = base64.b64decode(src[1])

filename = f'{name}.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```